# Find volume of the cap of a sphere of radius R with thickness h

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

I have to determine the volume and the formula for the volume for this spherical cap of height $h$, and the radius of the sphere is $R$:

[image: Volume of a sphere cap]

Two methods:  *I just need help setting up the triple integrals

1) Cylindrical

For for this method I am thinking that $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2 \pi$, $r$ from $0$ to $5$, and $z$ from $R-h$ to $R$ with the integral of $1\text{d}z\text{d}r\text{d}\theta$.  However, I'm not sure if this right??

2) Spherical

For this I know that $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2 \pi$, but I cannot figure out the range for $\phi$?? I know its from $0$ to some angle where the cap lies ($R-h$), however, I cannot figure it out.  Same goes for the range for $\rho$, for this I am assuming it would start at $(R-h)\sec\theta$ to what the outer boundary is? Sorry, I'm completely lost.

I've been working on this problem and trying to set it up for quite some time and have had no luck, and as a last resort, I am asking on here.
To whomever can help me, could you please keep it very detailed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set up the integral in sphericals, just draw a picture.  The limit in $\theta$ is determined by

$$\cos{\theta} = \frac{R-h}{R}$$

Therefore, the volume of the cap is the integral

$$2 \pi \, \int_0^{\arccos{[(R-h)/R]}} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, \int_{(R-h)/\cos{\theta}}^R dr \, r^2 $$

Comment: I do not understand the set up you have here, could you please do a triple integral set up in any order using dP dPhi and dtheta?

Comment: The $2 \pi$ is the integral over $\phi$.  That's it.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry i forgot to define the terms phi and theta, our textbook considers theta as the rotation, and the phi is the angle from the vertical z axis swiping down to the tip of the cap.  So this would mean the phi goes from 1 to arcos(R-h)/R and theta from 0 t 2pi correct?

Comment: @user109992: that would be correct.

Comment: Right right. Now i'm looking at the range for P, we have 0 to R, i am having a hard time understanding its 0 to R and not 2Rcosphi to R? because 0 would not consider the specifications of just the cap?

Comment: @user109992: I had to make an edit; the integral is the volume of a "sector" which include a cone volume.  I just subtracted the volume of the cone, which is found using a standard formula.

Comment: Instead of substracting, what would be the direct volume bounds? Sorry our professor wants us to do it with 3 bounds, and the answer would be: πh2(3R-h)/3

Comment: Can you please tell me how you find the lower bound of  r?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}
V_{\rm cap}&=\int_{\rm cap}\dd V\ =\
\overbrace{\int_{\rm cap}{1 \over 3}\,\nabla\cdot\vec{r}
\,\dd V
={1 \over 3}\int_{
\mbox{cap surface}}\vec{r}\cdot\dd\vec{S}}
^{\color{#c00000}{\ds{\mbox{Gauss Divergence Theorem}}}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\braces{%
\int_{\rm bottom}\bracks{-\pars{R - h}\,\verts{\dd S_{z}}}
+\int_{\rm top}R\,\hat{r}\cdot\dd\vec{S}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\braces{-\pars{R - h}\pi\bracks{R^{2} - \pars{R - h}^{2}}
+R^{3}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\phi\int_{0}^{\arccos\pars{\bracks{R - h}/R}}
\dd\theta\,\sin\pars{\theta}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\,\pi\braces{%
-\pars{R - h}\pars{2Rh - h^{2}} - 2R^{3}\bracks{{R - h \over R} - 1}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\,\pi\pars{-2R^{2}h + Rh^{2} + 2Rh^{2} - h^{3} + 2R^{2}h}
={1 \over 3}\,\pi\pars{3Rh^{2} - h^{3}}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#44f}{\large%
> V_{\rm cap} = \bracks{%
> {3 \over 4}\,\pars{h \over R}^{2} - {1 \over 4}\,\pars{h \over R}^{3}}\color{#c00000}{{4 \over 3}\,\pi R^{3}}}\,,\qquad\qquad 0 \leq h \leq 2R
> $$

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this problem using solids of revolution.

Define a circle as $x^2+y^2=R^2$

$\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$

By constructing wide circular cylinders on top of one another, decreasing in size as you move towards the top, one gets

$V=\int\limits_{R-h}^R\pi(R^2-y^2)dy\\=\left.\pi R^2y-\pi\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{R-h}^R=\pi Rh^2-\frac{1}{3}\pi h^3$

Comment: Stewart - Calculus v4 Section 6.2 q33

Answer (score 2):

I think that your cylindrical co-ordinates are wrong, because your bounds of z define horizontal planes, which results in your integral calculating the volume of a cylinder from $R-h$ to $R$. Instead of these bounds, I would choose from $R-h$ to $\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$. When evaluating the integral $$\int_0^{2 \pi}\int_0^R\int_{R-h}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}r\ \text{d}z \, \text{d}r\,\text{d}\theta$$ I get a similar solution to my previous answer: $\pi R^2h-\frac{1}{3}\pi R^3$. However, I cannot work out why the $R$'s and $h$'s are switched around (can anybody tell me why?).

For spherical co-ordinates, the bounds that you have started with are correct. For the rest, I get the same as Ron Gordon, except that I have defined my integral differently:
$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\arccos{\left(\frac{R-h}{R}\right)}} \int_{\frac{R-h}{\cos{\phi}}}^R \rho^2\sin{\phi}\, \text{d}\rho\, \text{d}\phi\, \text{d} \theta$$

Note that $\phi$ is evaluated *after* $\rho$, and not at the same time. An explanation for the upper bound of $\rho$ is that the upper surface of the cap is exactly $R$ units away from the origin. $\phi$ is defined at the edge of the cap where $R-h=R\cos\phi$, as Ron Gordon has said, so $\phi$ varies from $0$ to $\arccos\left(\frac{R-h}{R}\right)$.

I have tried evaluating this integral as well, but I am left with an extra term:

[image: working]

Again, if you can see where I went wrong in my calculations, please tell me.

Comment: Should be int 0->2pi like in the image. Unfortunately, the change can't be made as it is less than 6char.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that your integration limits are not correct (cylindrical ones). Take into account that the radius goes from zero to r, but not R (since the radius of the cap (r) is not the same that the radious of the sphere (R)).

If you try these other limits: $z:[R-h,R]$ and $r:[0,\sqrt{R^2-Z^2}]$, and evaluate the integral, the final expression is the correct one.